# When I use this script, it crashes my game. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to turn off the lights for a few seconds after an event is triggered, but it's not working. I'm still pretty new to C#, so if the code is ugly, I'm sorry :(

```
[SerializeField] static public bool lightsOut;
private Light lightComponent;

void Start()
{
    lightComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    if (DeleteAfterFix.isFixed1)
    {
        TurnOffLights();
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitAndTurnOn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    TurnLightsOn();
}

void TurnOffLights()
{
    Destroy(lightComponent);
    WaitAndTurnOn();
}

void TurnLightsOn()
{
    gameObject.AddComponent<Light>(); 
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().type = 0;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 1 / 3;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().range = 15 / 2;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().spotAngle = 165;
}
```

Comment: The value `DeleteAfterFix.isFixed1` never seems to get toggled to `false`. You are most likely getting a stack overflow or infinite loop with the amount of calls you are making.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html You need to use StartCoroutine with IEnumerator. Trigger a function in Update is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

in `Start()` function stops game time i.e. pauses the game. Remove that.

`WaitAndTurnOn` should be invoked as a Coroutine:

```
StartCoroutine(WaitAndTurnOn());
```

`Update` function not needed if you are using Coroutines.

```cs
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndTurnOn());
}

IEnumerator WaitAndTurnOn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    TurnLightsOn();
}

void TurnLightsOff()
{
    Destroy(GetComponent<Light>());
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndTurnOn());
}

void TurnLightsOn()
{
    gameObject.AddComponent<Light>(); 
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().type = 0;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 1 / 3;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().range = 15 / 2;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().spotAngle = 165;
}
```

Comment: `pauses the game.` this is not completely true though .. it only causes everything based on the time to "stop" but `Update` will still be Invoked every frame

Comment: Btw in your final example you again call `WaitAndTurnOn()` like it was a normal method ;)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68566921/7111561) the main issue is that you don't start your Coroutine as a Coroutine via [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Then it was mentioned, though a little bit misleading: You setting the

```c#
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

causes that the `WaitForSeconds` will never finish even if you would run it as a Coroutine.

You can actually keep the

```c#
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

but then you will have to use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) which ignores the timescale.

You could actually run your entirely code in one single routine using

```c#
[SerializeField] private Light lightComponent;

// Yes, if you do this Unity automatically runs Start as a Coroutine!
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    if(!lightComponent)lightComponent = GetComponent<Light>();

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => DeleteAfterFix.isFixed1);

    var oroginalScale = Time.timeScale;
    Time.timeScale = 0;

    // Instead of destroy rather only disable the component but keep it intact
    lightComponent.enabled = false;
  
    // wait for 2 seconds ignoring the timeScale  
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2f);

    // Simply enabled it again
    lightComponent.enabled = true;

    Time.timeScale = originalScale;
}
```